# HTML to JSON - extract only href attribute tag

Tags: php

I am currently able to convert HTML to JSON. I am able to parse the html with function `element_to_obj` and get back a json object with the html contents. Main concern: is it possible to only return in the json objects the values for `href` tags and disregard everything else?

```
function html_to_obj($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    return element_to_obj($dom->documentElement);
}

function element_to_obj($element) {
    $obj = array( "tag" => $element->tagName );
    foreach ($element->attributes as $attribute) {
        $obj[$attribute->name] = $attribute->value;
    }
    foreach ($element->childNodes as $subElement) {
        if ($subElement->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
            $obj["html"] = $subElement->wholeText;
        }
        else {
            $obj["children"][] = element_to_obj($subElement);
        }
    }
    return $obj;
}

$html = <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> This is a test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Go to a site? </h1>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <h1> Other sites to visit: </h1>
        <div><a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a></div>
        <div><a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a></div>
        <div><a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a></div>
        <div><a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a></div>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;

header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo json_encode(html_to_obj($html), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Just use an `if` statement to check the attribute name, and skip it if it's not `href`.

Comment: That would mean she would be checking all these other nodes that she has no interest in, and some pages can be pretty big, so it would take a long time to process all this unneeded stuff. Using `getElementsByTagName` should do the trick, in this case. I also can suggest to checkout `python scrapy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` and then iterate over all the elements.

```
<?php

function html_to_obj($html, $tag = 'a') {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    return element_to_obj($dom->getElementsByTagName($tag));
}

function element_to_obj($elements) {
    $obj = array();
    foreach($elements as $index => $element){

        $obj[$index] = array( "tag" => $element->tagName );
        foreach ($element->attributes as $attribute) {
            $obj[$index][$attribute->name] = $attribute->value;
        }
        foreach ($element->childNodes as $subElement) {
            if ($subElement->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
                $obj[$index]["html"] = $subElement->wholeText;
            }
            else {
                $obj[$index]["children"][] = element_to_obj($subElement);
            }
        }
    }

    return $obj;
}

$html = <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> This is a test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Go to a site? </h1>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <h1> Other sites to visit: </h1>
        <div><a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a></div>
        <div><a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a></div>
        <div><a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a></div>
        <div><a href="http://example.com">Some Site</a></div>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;

header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo json_encode(html_to_obj($html), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: this what i was looking for! As you mentioned in your comments i just wanted to avoid checking nodes that i had no interest in. The actual html is pretty darn big.

Comment: cool, you want your implementation to work a long time, so it's important to consider as much use cases as possible, to not have so much code debt later on

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that would to make a simple text parser.  Search through each JSON object looking for an instance of href=", then return the string after that (until the next non-escaped ").  If I recall correctly, Javascript has some basic functions such as string.substring that can work for this.  Alternatively, you could use a REGEX for that if you know how to use regexes.

Comment: This isn't Javascript, it's PHP.

Comment: True, but A:  he's using JSON, B: he's operating on html, which Javascript excels in and C: he never specified a PHP solution.

Comment: The question is tagged `php`, the code he's written is in PHP. It's operating on a `DOMDocument` object to create the JSON.

Comment: And no one in their right mind would do text parsing of JSON to manipulate it. You'd use `JSON.parse()` and then extract the parts that you want. But it looks like he wants to limit what he puts into the JSON in the first place.